# How can I get a link to be recognized by a search engine while being created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

I designed my own gallery which consists of a bunch of thumbnails on load, and when they are clicked on the image pops out to a bigger picture so the user can see it more clearly. On these pop out windows I have the ability to specify a URL which the user will be sent to if he/she clicks on the popped out image.

Because this whole gallery is being loaded by JavaScript, search engines will not be able to see the links that are attached to the pop out boxes. I thought about putting a text link also below the gallery thumbnails, but I think that would just make the gallery look sloppy. I have also thought about creating a hidden link, but I believe that will be ignored by the search engines and its frowned upon.

Anyone have any idea on how I can get this link to look good, and be visible by search engines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googlebot is able to construct much of the page and can access the onClick event contained in most tags. For now, if the onClick event calls a function that then constructs the URL, Googlebot can only interpret it if the function is part of the page (rather than in an external script).

Some examples of code that Googlebot can now execute include:

```
<div onclick="document.location.href='http://foo.com/'">
<tr onclick="myfunction('index.html')"><a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">new page</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('welcome.html')">open new window</a>
```

Comment: Is this true for an onclick event that is created after another onclick event? For instance, I click on the thumbnail, the popout box is created with the onclick event attached to the image?

Comment: Yes that still hold. It's the same as in the Example i provided above where a function() is called on `onclick`

Comment: Ok cool....So in this case I should be good with the way it is? Do you know any way to test out what google sees on my gallery?

Comment: As soon as Google indexes your links, you'll be able to verify this.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess if we all assume that Google is the only search engine, or that all search engines use Googlebot, then things are fine. But if you want to be sure you are truly search engine optimized, there are better suggestions here.

Comment: If Google indexes your site, then all other search engines will get your links from Google.

Comment: @Hussein Well, it's been proven that you can Google on Bing, and Yahoo is powered by Bing, so maybe you are right. But Bing does also use its own MSNBot, and Bing will use those results first before it determines that Google has better results. I would say it's better to be optimized for all helpful search bots now and in the future than to code for a specific bot. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your thumbnails link to the bigger picture and use JavaScript to ignore that actual link and open the popup with your current functionality. The thumbnails will get indexed and the links will get spider-ed as well.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea.....Let me think about that a minute. Your basically saying create a dummy link?

Comment: Well that's the first thing that pops in my mind, i'm no SEO expert but that's what i would do. Just create A tags and wrap your thumnail inside. fire the onclick on the a tag as your are probably already doing.

Comment: I've been told that onclick is bad ;)  - the new best practices point to using unobtrusive javascript. Basically instead of doing an onclick, attach a class, or wrap all the links in a div and attach events to the objects using a javascript framework (jquery in your case). There are two suggestions below for using event.preventDefault(), and that will do what Michael is suggesting, but without needing to mix javascript and markup. It also has the advantage of allowing your links to work for people with js disabled, but giving users with js enabled a more rich experience.

Comment: @nerdfury i think your right, i was not referring to the actual onclick although my explanation can easily be read as if i did suggest that. As far as i know its best practice to use click event using jQuery like so: $('myClass').click(function(){ //do something });

Comment: right on. Re-reading with that in mind makes it clearer. It was actually your comment above where you said "onclick" that made me question it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the link right around your thumbnail:

```
<a href="fullsized.htm" class="thumb"><img src="thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

Bind your expand function to the link and cancel the default behavior in your javascript:

```
$("a.thumb").click(function(e)
{
    // show the larger version
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery event.preventDefault(); This will prevent the link action from happening, and you can do what you want to do with javascript. This is a good way of allowing sites to work for users without javascript enabled, but adding nice features for those that do. This way, the search engines will see the link and follow it, and users will still get the rich javascript experience you are creating.

```
<a href="link-to-page1.html" class="thumb-link">
  <img src="thumbnail1.png" alt="thumb 1" />
</a>

<a href="link-to-page2.html" class="thumb-link">
  <img src="thumbnail2.png" alt="thumb 2" />
</a>

<a href="link-to-page3.html" class="thumb-link">
  <img src="thumbnail3.png" alt="thumb 3" />
</a>
```

then in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thumb-link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel the hyperlink default action
    // do your javascript here
  });
});
```